# Symfony override _locale parameter

Tags: php, symfony

I have created a custom LocaleListener:

```php
class LocaleListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {    
        if ($request->getSession()->get("language")) {
            $lang = $request->getSession()->get("language");
        } else {
            $lang = $request->getPreferredLanguage(array("de", "en"));
        }

        $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $lang);
        $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $lang));
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 17)),
        );
    }
}
```

I get the language code from session (if exists) or from browser. Now I would like to correct / manipulate the route. I am using `_locale` in my router to set the language code (`en` or `de`). Now I would like override the user's choice.

For example, the language code in the `LocaleListener` is `de`. The user does now request the url which `_locale` = `en` (example: `/en` instead of automatically `/de`).

How can I force to set the users `_locale` to my result form the `LocaleListener` outside of every controller, with a listener or an other solution?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to add RedirectResponse

```
$event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($request->getBaseUrl().'/'.$locale.'/'.($params ? '?'.http_build_query($params) : '')));
```

or use JMSI18nRoutingBundle https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I need to get `$params`? Also I think this will create an redirect loop. We just need the redirection if the `$lang` not equal to the `$_locale`. Conclusion: We need to get also `$params` and the `$_locale` from the router.

Comment: $params you can get from  $request->query->all(); $locale form $request->getLocale()

Comment: And whats about the $_locale to pervent loops?